# Relationship between finite VC dimension and Lipschitzness

Tags: vc-dimension

It appears that functions  with finite VC dimension can not "change too fast", so they have to be Lipschitz.
Is this the case?
Is there a known relation between VC dimension and Lipschitzness?

Comment: The VC dimension is defined for *sets of functions*, not for functions. If you want to interpret a function $f$ as the singleton set $\{ f \}$, then the VC dimension is always $0$ regardless of the Lipschitz constant (see "constant classifier" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_dimension#Examples )

Comment: For this question to make sense, you need to make some additional assumptions: if the set of functions $V = \{ f_\theta \}$ is parametrized by a parameter $\theta$, then we need to assume that the space $V$ and the parameter space $\Theta$ are both metric spaces (say with metrics $d_V$ and $d_\Theta$). This is necessary to define the Lipschitz constant $L$ as the inf of constants $K \ge 0$ that satisfy the inequality $d_V (f_\theta, f_\phi) \le K d_\Theta (\theta, \phi)$ for all $\theta, \phi \in \Theta$.

Comment: But now the answer to the question depends on which metrics you choose for these spaces. For example, with the discrete metric on both spaces ($d_V (f, g) = \delta_{fg}$ and $d_\Theta (i, j) = \delta_{ij}$), every class of functions would be Lipschitz with $L = 1$, regardless of the VC dimension.

Comment: Thank you. But if a class has finite VC dimension, does not it mean that each function from this class  can identify only a finite set of sub-domains which belong to each class? Can we deduce a property of a function from the fact that it belongs to a class with finite VC dimension?

Comment: Suppose, we have some Lp measure on both spaces. What would it mean for Lipschitzness?

Comment: Take any function $f$. The class $V = \{f\}$ has VC dimension 0. So you can't deduce anything about $f$ from a finite VC dimension.

Comment: Got it! Thank you.